# How to compile mbed main.c++ and main.h file in Linux eclips to get build files(.elf.hex)

Tags: linux, eclipse, stm32f4discovery, mbed

I will be very thankful if someone explain how to use .c++ and .h file in eclips using Ubuntu platform to compile it and get the .elf, .hex and .bin file.
I have some files from mbed STM32f4 board.
Please guide me 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Build via [mbed CLI](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-cli). After installing set your build command in Eclipse to:

   `mbed compile -m YOUR_BOARD -t GCC_ARM --profile ./mbed-os/tools/profiles/debug.json`
2. Build via a Makefile. In the mbed Online Compiler right click on your project, select *Export > Eclipse (GCC ARM)*. This will give you an Eclipse project with the makefile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is i only have header and source file and i don't have the link on mbed web page for the particular files to get export folder with makefile from there. That's why i asked  how to use header and source file to get make file. I'm using openocd and GCC arm compiler in Eclips

Comment: Well, you'll need to craft a Makefile then specific to your target. Best to use an example as there's a lot of define's involved. F.e. [here's one for NUCLEO F411RE](https://gist.github.com/janjongboom/c572c100fd4d900c657cedb6949b862b). You can get one for your board by exporting mbed-os-example-blinky to the right board.